# Dependency Injection Failover in Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Is it possible to specify another bean to inject in case that the first intended bean to be injected fails?

Lets say we have Bean1, Bean2, and Bean3. Bean1 requires Bean2 but if Bean2 fails to be injected for some reason, then I want Bean3 to be injected instead. But each time Bean1 is retrieved from the container, it should always try to inject Bean2 first before attempting to inject Bean3. Is this possible? If not, what are my options?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?  This conditional dependency injection sounds like an attempt at solving something that likely has a better solution.

Comment: Can you suggest why injection of Bean2 can fail?

Comment: Because bean2 maybe a bean that is being looked up from another server  before it gets injected which of course will fail when that server is down. There could be other reasons as well.

Answer (score 1):

Per me the question is flawed. In normal circumstances, Spring is supposed to be used for injecting the beans declaratively. So as pointed out by @Don Roby, @Adrian Shum the problem you are trying to solve is not for Spring.

Spring is not designed to resolve the dependency for you dynamically like a Service Locator.

Comment: +1. Create a bean to use as a Service Locator and let that bean do your dynamic look-up logic.

Comment: @Nilesh I don't think what I want to achieve will make things non-declarative. In fact introducing a service locator will make it non-declarative. I don't see anything wrong with Spring providing that feature. AFAIK dependency injection was invented to replace service locators wasn't it?